# Android Studio layout way off on different devices

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I'm trying to make a maze app. Only I notice a problem.

The whole maze is designed in XML using only dp as dimensions, but it still looks way off on certain phones. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="xander.woutzijnemptyactivity.MainActivity"
>

    <!-- Power ups -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ball_dimension"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ball_dimension"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/power_up_0"
        android:src="@drawable/power_up_pink"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ball_dimension"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ball_dimension"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/power_up_1"
        android:src="@drawable/power_up_red"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ball_dimension"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ball_dimension"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/power_up_2"
        android:src="@drawable/power_up_blue"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp" />

    <!-- Ball -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ball_dimension"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ball_dimension"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/ball"
        android:src="@drawable/ball_128"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />

    <!-- Four border walls -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/wall0"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/wall1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="566dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/wall2"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/wall3"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <!-- Maze walls -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/wall_width"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/wall4"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/wall_width"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/wall5"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="121dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/wall_width"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/wall6"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="225dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/wall_width"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/wall7"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="225dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/wall_width"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/wall8"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="189dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/wall_width"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/wall9"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="189dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="time: "
        android:id="@+id/timeText"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please include the code of how you're drawing it.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak this is the xml code

Comment: And please also include the code where you set the margins. It seems like you do this at runtime for some parts

Comment: I don't believe I ever set any margins what so ever. This is the whole xml file. In the general code I only use code from this xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to let anyone searching for an answer to this problem know my solution.
I made my own unit system. A so called block, this was the screenwidth devided by 80 in my case. This gives you a unit to work with that scales for all resolution. With this solution something is always the same proportion in regards to your screen.

Answer (score 0):

You're centering your border walls.

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="500dp"
  android:layout_height="10dp"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  android:id="@+id/wall2"
  android:background="#000000"
  android:alpha="1"
  android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/> <--- THIS ONE
```

Remove `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and apply a margin to the left like to the left wall, then it should work:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
```

Comment: Yes I know that helps. But I keep having the problem that on some screens the maze fits well and on others it still falls off. Just like in the picture in my question. I thought that by using dp that this should not happen. But apparently it does.

Comment: @sateeprikker dp is for independent *sizes*. If you were to put a ruler on the screen, it would be around the same size on each. You need relative sizes, compared to screen width, this is somewhat more complicated

Comment: Ah. So you mean that if I use the same dp on a 5 inch screen (and on this it fits) that it will fall of on a 4 inch screen? And do you have any suggestions how I should fix this then?

Comment: @sateeprikker Exactly. But as I said, I don't know of any easy solution, since this requires measuring dimensions and adapting all your sizes accordingly :/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, only using dp as dimensions won't help you much.

**Creating different layout files for different screen sizes is the solution.**

Please read *[Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)*. It contains all the information you need.